# Distance between `<td>` = 0

Tags: html, css, html-table

Can I set the distance from one `<td>` to another `<td>` to zero? I paste here the code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:212px;">
       <h3 id="skills">  <input id="skills_check" type="checkbox" name="skills" /> Appraise &#9705</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt">int</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt"><input type="text" name="skill_mod" style="width:30px" />&nbsp=</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt"><input type="text" name="ability_mod" style="width:30px;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;" />&nbsp+</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt"><input type="text" name="ranks" style="width:30px;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;" />&nbsp+</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt"><input type="text" name="misc_mod" style="width:30px;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;" /></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:212px;">
       <h3 id="skills"><input id="skills_check" type="checkbox" name="skills" />Appraise &#9705</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt">int</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt"><input type="text" name="skill_mod" style="width:30px" />&nbsp=</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt"><input type="text" name="ability_mod" style="width:30px;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;" />&nbsp+</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt"><input type="text" name="ranks" style="width:30px;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;" />&nbsp+</h3>
    </td>
    <td>
       <h3 id="skills_opt"><input type="text" name="misc_mod" style="width:30px;border-top:none;border-left:none;border-right:none;" /></h3>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

that `<td>`'s are too far from each other, they should be closer.

Comment: You gave the td which contains those to 212px - http://jsfiddle.net/jvw3z/

Comment: Begin by closing your tags in a valid way (like H3) and then please give additional details on your question, maybe a live example, i don't understand at all what you're asking.

Comment: The td has the width which you gave them, 212px. Remove the styles and it would be the width of the text inside it

Answer (score 1):

Set [`border-collapse`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-collapse) to `collapse` on the table element.

Comment: Define "real browser". If you mean "when it is on your website" then you probably have some other CSS interfering with the rule.

Answer (score 1):

I think you refer to the column with "Appraise" word. If this is true, remove the style which includes the width and **don't forget** to close all the `<h3>` tags.

Also, you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7a6wr/) your code cleaned up an functioning correctly.